# How do I skip headers in CSV file in WSO2 Micro Integrator

Tags: csv, wso2, wso2-esb, smooks, wso2-integration-studio

I am using smooks mediator to convert csv file to json using VFS. We have an option to skip header row while using the CSV connector/module. How do I skip the first row of headers while processing the file in WSO2 Integration studio using smooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Smooks` configurtion add the following option.

```
skiplines="1"
```

Full Smooks Config

```xml
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.5.xsd">
<csv:reader fields="name,age,address" separator="," quote="'" skipLines="1" />
</smooks-resource-list>
```

Comment: I am using http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.0.xsd xsd for reading the csv file and using  <param name="skipLines">1</param>  to skip the header. But it isn't affecting the output.

Comment: Is any extra xsd required here?

Comment: @Ruby `skipLines` was introduced in Smooks 1.4 hence you need to use the `csv:reader` to use this option. I updated my answer please have a look.